# Why does this Doctrine EntityListener not work in Symfony6?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

On Symfony 6.3, I Use this listener based [on the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners). It calculates additional data before saving an entity:

```php
<?php
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Simulation;
use App\Goflex\Simulator;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Attribute\AsEntityListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

#[AsEntityListener(event: Events::preUpdate, method: 'consolidate', entity: Simulation::class)]
class SimulationConsolidator
{
    private function consolidate(Simulation $simulation, $event): void
    {
        // for debugging purpose
        throw new \Exception("test"); 
        // My logic...
        $simulation->setXxxxx();
    }
}
```

The controller works as expected - ie it does saves my entity:

```php
// ...
class SimulationController extends AbstractController
{
    // ...
    public function save(Simulation $simulation, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        $success = true;
        $errorMsg = null;

        try {
            $form = $this->createForm(SimulationType::class, $simulation);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
                if(true !== $form->isValid()) {
                    foreach($form->getErrors(true) as $error) {
                        $errorMsg .= $error->getMessage()."\n";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $em->persist($simulation);
                    $em->flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $success = false;
            $errorMsg = $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->json([
            'success' => $success,
            'errorMsg' => $errorMsg,
        ]);
    }
```

I tried declaring the listener in services.yaml:

```yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\SimulationConsolidator:
        tags:
            -
                name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener'
                event: 'preUpdate'
                entity: 'App\Entity\Simulation'
                method: 'consolidate'
```

And interestingly this error occured:
**Entity Listener "App\EventListener\SimulationConsolidator#consolidate()" in "App\Entity\Simulation" was already declared, but it must be declared only once.**

Which means my Listener **is** declared, only never triggered. I "should" be getting my "test" Exception at least. Why does it not trigger?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was elsewhere. The fields I tried to update in my tests were related to a relational entity... The `Simulation` entity itself was not updated, hence not triggering the Listener.

Sadly I ended up using a less elegant approach: using a service to "manually" call the `consolidate` method whenever needed - when saving.